# Keeping Python interpreter alive in Excel

Tags: python, excel

I would like to develop a Python program that can be called directly from Excel, for example clicking a button on a sheet.

So far it is easy, I know how to go about it, but the problem is that the program has many heavy imports and static variables that need to be defined only once.

If I call a Python script from excel, every function call initialise a new interpreter and this is time consuming.

I was wondering, is there a way to “keep the Python interpreter alive” once excel starts and then basically use this Python interpreter every time I want to execute a function?

I know I could do it with xlwings that creates a connection between Python and excel but then I can’t use excel buttons to call the functions.
Unfortunately the requirement is that the front end must be in excel.

I don’t even know what to Google for, so every suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use an Excel addin that runs Python within the add-in.

Your alternatives are:

- xlSlim - https://www.xlslim.com - commercial (I am the author)
- PyXLL - https://www.pyxll.com - commercial
- xlOil - https://xloil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Introduction.html - free
- xlwings - https://www.xlwings.org - free

I have an example of calling a Python function from a button in my xlSlim documentation.

If you save this little Python function:

```
XLSLIM_COMAPPFUNC = None

def PythonRules():
        excel_obj = XLSLIM_COMAPPFUNC()
        app = excel_obj.Application
        app.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value = "Python Rules!"
```

and register the module using xlSlim:

```
=RegisterPyModule("c:\users\russe\documents\vbareplacement.py")
```

You will then be able to assign the function PythonRules() to a button using the regular Excel Assign Macro window.

See the documentation here:
https://russelwebber.github.io/xlslim-docs/html/user/vba_replacement.html